# Discord.js .cleanContent property lost on Object.keys(), and not loggable

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I have a Discord.js [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message) instance, which, as defined in the documentation, should have a `.cleanContent` property, and it should be a string.

- `console.log(message.cleanContent)` works as intended, but
  `console.log(message)` does not log the `cleanContent` property.
- More so, `Object.keys(message)` does not discover the `cleanContent`    property.
- However, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(message))` has a  loggable,    visible `cleanContent` in turn.
- A `for(key in message)` loop also does not list the `.cleanContent`.

So, uh.. what is going on here?

The bug is reproducable with this much code:

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  console.log(Object.keys(message))
})
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Added a snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that it's a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), as shown [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/Message.js#L474). Getters don't seem to be logged in node.js, unlike in my browser's developer console (Chrome). Getters are different in different environments, so it's difficult to provide a solution.

Comment: Seems to be the case. Is there, then, a way to "trigger" those getters before running `Object.keys()` on the object?

Comment: @almarc it works in my browser, the getters are shown in both for loop and `Object.keys()`, however, node.js does not seem to want to log it